# How to delete row in table?

Tags: javascript, html

I want delete row which I created in function `add()`. When I use function `deleteRow()` row will be deleted but I can't use my `add()` function again. Someone knows why?

```
var trIdP =0;
function add() {
 var typeP = document.getElementById("typeP").value;
 var valueP = document.getElementById("valueP").value;
 var newText = document.createTextNode(typeP);
 var newText2 = document.createTextNode(valueP+" Eur");
 var newText3 = document.createTextNode("button");
 var tablePr = document.getElementById("tableP").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 if ((typeP != "") && (valueP != "")) {       
     var newRow = tablePr.insertRow(trIdP);
     newRow.id = ("trP"+trIdP);
     var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
     var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
     var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

     newCell1.appendChild(newText);
     newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
     newCell3.innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"deleteRow("+trIdP+")\"><img   src=\"x.gif\" alt=\"Delete row\"></a>";

     document.getElementById("typeP").value = "";
     document.getElementById("valueP").value = "";

     trIdP++;
 }
}

function deleteRow(id){
      document.getElementById("trP"+id).remove();
}
```

Comment: It might help to see your HTML as well. See [mcve]

Comment: Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You're forgetting to decrease the trIdP counter.</strike>

Update:

```
// Code goes here

var trIdP = 0;

function add() {
  var typeP = document.getElementById("typeP").value;
  var valueP = document.getElementById("valueP").value;
  var newText = document.createTextNode(typeP);
  var newText2 = document.createTextNode(valueP + " Eur");
  var newText3 = document.createTextNode("button");
  var tablePr = document.getElementById("tableP").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  if ((typeP !== "") && (valueP !== "")) {
    var newRow = tablePr.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.id = "trP" + trIdP;
    var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

    newCell1.appendChild(newText);
    newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
    newCell3.innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"deleteRow(" + trIdP + ")\"><div>Row: " + trIdP + "</div></a>";

    document.getElementById("typeP").value = "";
    document.getElementById("valueP").value = "";

    trIdP++;
  }
}

function deleteRow(id) {
  document.getElementById("trP" + id).remove();
}
```

[Check out this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WtaBtlEc1yunZ8MDqsQ6?p=preview)

Comment: Also you can use the -1 in the inserRow as it can be seen [here...](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

Comment: It works but it is iteresting now because when for example create 3 times row and delete row with id 2 and again create new row, new row have id 3 like last row. Why when I click delete row in row with id 3 not delete 2 rows with same ids it is illogical.

Comment: When you place the index, you can't jump one position. Let's say you have 2 rows and you want to place a third. You can't place it in the fourth position. I've updated the plunker to use an unique ID.

Comment: When you get an element by id you retrieve the first element matching id.